# Python: Divide by zero error with leastsq calculations

Tags: python, gaussian, least-squares, divide-by-zero

I am performing a Gaussian fit to some data (from file prplt). I keep getting the following errors: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  return (y1-func(x2,p))/err

AND

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  z=p[0]*np.exp(-(x2-p[1])**2/(2*p[2]**2))

At first, I thought that it was just because I had guessed badly at the initial parameters p0, but I am now convinced it is something else. Here is my code:

```
x1= np.linspace(1,len(prplt),len(prplt))
index=np.where(x1>340)
x2= x1[index]
y=prplt
y1=y[index]
def func(x2,p):
    z=p[0]*np.exp(-(x2-p[1])**2/(2*p[2]**2))
    return z
p0=[3500.,400.,50.]
def errfunc(p,x2,y1,func,err):
    return (y1-func(x2,p))/err

plt.errorbar(x2, y1, np.sqrt(y1), ecolor='black', fmt=None)
out=leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(x2,y1,func,np.sqrt(y1)),full_output=1)
```

Any insight would be appreciated! I am a very frustrated new programmer.
Thank you for reading!

Comment: in `def func(x2,p):` add print statements before the math to print out x2 and p on separate lines.  Check that these are what you thought they should be. For instance, it appears p should be an array with at least 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your `err` is 0, which raises the error.
Your code does not supply the source of `err` so we can assist. But you can try to try to trace it back with a debugger (or some print statements if you are not comfortable with it).
There also seems to be a value that is usable in your other expression (maybe `p2 == 0`). You should debug the source of this value as well.